# Select or delete multiple layers at once - Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, layers, selections

The title is pretty much self-explanatory.

**How do you select and or delete multiple layers at once in Inkscape?**

I've tried holding CTRL and SHIFT while selecting layers, but to no avail. For some reason my Google Search is only yielding results for Gimp, Illustrator, Photoshop--basically everything but Inkscape. I've tried looking on YT--same story. :/

Answer (score 3):

You're right, this can't be done with the GUI however if your desire is high enough you can easily (and quickly) open up the SVG file in a text editor and delete the layer nodes manually.

I'd save the file as plain SVG rather than the Inkscape flavour and you'll see that layers are actually group elements `<g>` with the layer name as an id. You'll be deleting from the start of the `<g>` tag up to and including the closing `</g>`. In doing so you will delete any content on that layer. Empty layers won't have the closing `</g>`.

You can ruin your file doing this so I'd recommend some source control of your choosing before you start.

Comment: I'll def consider that for next time. The reason I didn't bother with that is because each layer is a single stroke/path, and if I save as Plain SVG the path IDs are just random 4 digit numbers, so I'd have no clue what was what :/ For some reason the only way I get info when I open it up in a text editor is if I save as Inkscape SVG, and then the groups/layers have IDs which were the layer names

Comment: any idea how to set a default stroke style?

Comment: @user2230470 if http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=9258 doesn't answer your (unrelated) question I'd start a new question. HTH